# InvalidAccountData Passing a price id to rust pyth-sdk program from typescript client - Pyth

Tags: rust, typescript, transaction-instructions, oracles

I'm trying to use pyth SDK make a program to fetch a price, then using a typescript client to pass the id of the price feed I want to the program.
My rust lib.rs is essentially this:

```
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let price_account_info = next_account_info(account_iter)?;
    msg!("Account key: {}", price_account_info.key.to_string());
    let price_feed: PriceFeed = load_price_feed_from_account_info(&price_account_info).unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

of course I should then use the price feed to actually get the data, but I've limited my code unto the line where I believe the issue lie (and removed here the imports for readability). This has been build and deployed correctly on the devnet.

In typescript (also removing parts for readability) I do this:

```
const programKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(programSecretKey);
const programPublicKey = programKeypair.publicKey;
const SOLUSDString = 'J83w4HKfqxwcq3BEMMkPFSppX3gqekLyLJBexebFVkix'; // SOL/USD price feed id
const SOLUSDpublicKey = new PublicKey(SOLUSDString);

const transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.add(
  new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [{pubkey: SOLUSDpublicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}],
    programId: programPublicKey
  }),
);

const payerKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(payerSecretKey);
const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com', 'confirmed');

const txHash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [payerKeypair],
);
```

I get the following error message:

> 'Program 4CkxyEHCCr4MTvfyWjc49CyK6mZnsz8FgTUHrJMk4AsA invoke [1]',
> 'Program log: Account key: J83w4HKfqxwcq3BEMMkPFSppX3gqekLyLJBexebFVkix',
> "Program log: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidAccountData', src/lib.rs:31:88",
> 'Program 4CkxyEHCCr4MTvfyWjc49CyK6mZnsz8FgTUHrJMk4AsA consumed 14281 of 200000 compute units',
> 'Program 4CkxyEHCCr4MTvfyWjc49CyK6mZnsz8FgTUHrJMk4AsA failed: SBF program panicked'

notice that lib.rs:31 is indeed the call to `load_price_feed_from_account_info()`. So, it seems to me that the price id enters my program but somehow the related price account isn't accepted by the function. I think it could be something I specified incorrectly in the "keys" argument of `new TransactionInstruction`. I've tried to set `isWritable` to true but the error persists.

Thank you for reading; hope someone can help me.

Comment: It's unfortunately not possible to tell just from this info. `load_price_feed_from_account_info` is having an issue deserializing the account you've provided, but the address appears correct on devnet. In that case, there might be a problem with `load_price_feed_from_account_info`

Comment: thank you for your reply; I think indeed the problem is that I'm not serializing anything at all